# CSS tables - fit two boxes inside cell by 7:3 ratio

Tags: html, css

Here is a cell with two blocks, inside it is a `<textarea>` and a `<div>`.

```html
<table style="width:100%; border:solid 1px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:70%">
      <textarea rows="9" style="background-color:#ee9; width:100%;"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%">
      <div style=" width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#eaa; border:solid 1px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make these completely fit inside the table by a 70:30 ratio?
[image]

Comment: for such a dispatch, flex or grid is plenty efficient ... HTML table is not made for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flex is a better option :

```css
body >div{
display:flex;
}
body >div textarea {
flex:7;
margin:2px;
}
body >div > div {
flex:3;
margin:2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <textarea rows="9" style="background-color:#ee9;"></textarea>
      <div style="background-color:#eaa; border:solid 1px;"></div>
</div>
```

grid is too

```css
body>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
  grid-gap:4px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea rows="9" style="background-color:#ee9;"></textarea>
  <div style="background-color:#eaa; border:solid 1px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `grid` layout to make this thing as follows.

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <textarea rows="9" style="background-color:#ee9; width:100%;"></textarea>
  <div style=" width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#eaa; border:solid 1px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css flex-basis property

```
<div style="display:flex;width: 300px;height: 100px;border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;">
<div style="flex-basis: 70%;padding:0;background:yellow"></div>
<div style="flex-basis: 30%;padding:0;background:red"></div>
</div>
```